# XCode 5 having problems adding an app icon

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I'm getting the following warning when I add an icon to the Images.xcassets folder (iPhone App iOS 7 60pt).

"A 60x60@2x app icon is required for iPhone apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later"

I'm not an expert in this area but from what I can see my png file is correct.

The image properties are:
Size 120 x 120 pixels
Color Space  sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Idiom iPhone
Size 60
Scale 2X
and the name is Weatherx60@2x.png
How do I fix this?

Comment: When you look at the Images.xcassets collection in Xcode, and open the AppIcon asset, do you see the icon in the iPhone App iOS 7 slot?

Comment: I did ... it is when I click on it that I see the properties I listed above.

Comment: In case it explains the error, the app image has a black border (maybe 2 pixels) when it appears on the iPhone.